# Remove "via APP_NAME" on post made from facebook graph api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, post, feed

Currently, I'm using RestClient to make simple posts to friends' timelines.

```
RestClient.post 'https://graph.facebook.com/_friend_/feed', :access_token => "_token_", :message => "_message_"
```

This works, but when it appears on my friend's timeline, there is text at the bottom of the post that says "via APP_NAME". Is there any way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - only Facebook's site can do that.  3rd party apps will always show what app it was posted by.

Comment: my application is not showing it on page posts...how to make it appear??

Comment: @WorldGamer tell me how :)

Comment: @AnuradhaJayathilaka it can be easily done in settings of ure app page..[under developer.facebook.com ]

Comment: @WorldGamer stating which settings and what values would be more helpful

Comment: This seems to indicate they removed it: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/12/18/facebook-to-remove-attribution-when-pages-post-via-third-party-apps/

Comment: @levi there is no solution for this atm. posting to fb pages will never show via app name.