# Publish (Post) On Facebook Without App Name

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token, facebook-public-feed-api

I want to remove my Facebook application name. See the highlighted part.

[image]

Is it available to remove the application name if I have all the permissions I need?

Application should post on behalf of authorized user (suppose I have all the necessary permissions by the user).

Comment: how are you posting?  any code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014659/remove-via-app-name-on-post-made-from-facebook-graph-api-in-rails?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation like yours, i did researched on it for hours but then came to know that, if your are posting to facebook via an external app then it will show application name for sure.

Comment: Can you provide any confirmation link? From Facebook's developer pages?