# Can we remove “via APP_NAME” on post made from facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Similar question is posted here:
[Remove "via APP_NAME" on post made from facebook graph api in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014659/remove-via-app-name-on-post-made-from-facebook-graph-api-in-rails)

This question was answered in Jan'12.

Late'12 their were multiple reports of facebook removing "Via App" attribution. e.g. [DigitalTrends](http://www.digitaltrends.com/social-media/facebook-removing-attribution-via-3rd-party-apps/)

A related study of content published directly v/s app - [Hubspot study](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/32124/Facebook-Content-Published-Via-Third-Party-Tools-Suffers-67-Fewer-Likes-New-Data.aspx)

But I don't see any effect!?
[image: App Attribution in facebook status]

Can it be done or not?
Can't find any official annoucement regarding this.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate, because the answer is still correct.

Comment: _“Late'12 their were multiple reports of facebook removing "Via App" attribution. e.g. DigitalTrends”_ – if you read _carefully_, you notice that this is for posts on Facebook pages, not user profiles. For the former it was removed; for the latter it can’t be.